# "Orthogonal complement" in normed spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed space, $M\subset X$. Then the set $M^\perp=\{\varphi\in X^\ast:\;\forall x\in M\;\varphi(x)=0\}$ called "orthogonal complement" (or annihilator) for $M$. My question is how to find it in a particular case. For instance:

> Find the annihilator of the set $M=\{x\in C[-1,1]:\;\forall t<0\;x(t)=0\}.$

I'm starting to reason like this: we know the general form of a linear bounded functional on $C[-1,1]$: $\varphi(x)=\displaystyle\int\limits_{-1}^1x(t)dg(t)$, where $g$ -- bounded variation function on $[-1,1]$, such that $g(-1)=0$ and she’s everywhere continuous on the left. According to the conditions we have $\varphi(x)=\displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^1x(t)dg(t)=0$. So it seems $g(t)=\text{const}$ for all $t\in[0,1]$ but what does it give?

**Edit.** I found a statement from which it follows what is needed: if $g$ has a bounded variation on segment $[a,b]$ and $\forall x\in C[a,b]$ $\displaystyle\int\limits_{a}^bx(t)dg(t)=0$ then $g(t)=g(a)$ a.e.

Now I don't understand the following task:

> Find the annihilator of the set $M=\{x\in C[0,1]:\;\forall a<b\;x(a)\leq x(b)\}$.

As I understand, $M$ it's a set of continuous non-decreasing functions. There is an answer to this problem: $M^\perp=\{0\}$, but as it knows, this means that $M$ is dense in $C[0,1]$. But can this be right? Is it possible to bring any continuous function to non-decreasing with any accuracy?

And if this answer is incorrect, then how to find the right one? Is there any way to use the previous method?

Comment: Wouldn't the answer that $g$ is constant on $[0,1]$ be sufficient to describe all elements in $M^\perp$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition $\ M^\perp = \{0\}\ $ doesn't require $\ M\ $ to be dense in $\ C[0,1]\ $, merely that the *linear subspace spanned by $\ M\ $* be dense in $\ C[0,1]\ $.

If $\ \ell\in M^\perp\ $ and $\ x\in C[0,1]\ $ is absolutely continuous on $\ [0,1]\ $, then $\ x\ $ can be expressed as the difference $\ x_+-x_-\ $ between two absolutely continuous non-decreasing functions on $\ [0,1]\ $, so $\ x_+,x_-\in M\ $, and $\ \ell(x)=$$\ell(x_+)-$$\ell( x_-)=0\ $.  Since the functions absolutely continuous on $\ [0,1]\ $ are dense in $\ C[0,1]\ $ and $\ \ell(x)=0\ $ for all such $\ x\ $ it follows that $\ \ell=0\ $.

Comment: The density of absolutely continuous in space continuous is unfamiliar to me. Where can I see this result? Or it's obvious?

Comment: No, it's not obvious.  The [online encyclopedia of mathematics](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Absolute_continuity#Absolute_continuity_of_a_function) has a good summary of the more important properties of absolutely continuous functions, including the existence of a density.  It cites the 1969 edition of Royden's *Real Analysis* for the proof.  In the fourth edition of 2010 by Royden and Fitzpatrick it's theorem 11 of Chapter 6 (p.125).

Comment: I'm sorry, but you gave me a link to the following property: an absolutely continuous function on a segment is always specified using an indefinite integral. But how does the density in space of continuous come from here? What sequence of absolutely continuous converges to an arbitrary continuous in the sup-norm?

Comment: I'm sorry; owing to the ambiguity of the word "density", I misunderstood your request. Since any polynomial on $\ [0,1]\ $ is absolutely continuous, and polynomials on $\ [0,1]\ $ are dense in $\ C[0,1]\ $ by the [Stone–Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone–Weierstrass_theorem), it follows that the absolutely continuous functions on $\ [0,1]\ $ are dense in $\ C[0,1]\ $.

Comment: Thank you, everything really turned out to be almost obvious. Could you please tell me if it’s not difficult: $M=\{x\in l_1:\; \xi_1>\xi_2>\xi_3>...\}$. In such a problem the principle is the same (we need to somehow represent finite sequences in the form of a linear monotone combination) or do something else?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what the set $\ M=\left\{x\in l_1:\xi_1>\xi_2>\xi_3>\dots\right\}\ $ is here.  What are $\ \xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3, \dots\ $ ? How are they related to $\ x\ $?